# Why Plug-In Meta Data Import truncate table names?

Tags: datastage

I'm using Datastage 11.3.

When I try to import table definition via "Plug-In Meta Data Import", it truncates too long table names.

There is a way to prevents it from doing this?

---

I'm using the wizard, but if I want to use plug-in I still get the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried importing it via ODBC table definitions or Orchestrate schema definitions instead of Plug-In Meta Data Import? How long is your table name?

Comment: via Orchestrate it truncates field that are longer than 18 (for example decimal 38 is turned in decimal 18)

ODBC, i'm working on the client machine.

Comment: This is confusing - your question is about truncted table names and now you are writing that a data type got truncated. So what is your point?

Comment: If i use Orchestrate it truncates data type, if i use plug-in it truncates table names